# product page - AJAX add to cart function not working / cant send data to server database

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel

This is my code:

```
@extends('layout.home')

@section('title', 'Activity')

@section('content')
    <!-- Shop Detail Start -->
    <div class="container-fluid py-5">
        <div class="row px-xl-5">
            <div class="col-lg-5 pb-5">
                <div id="product-carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                    <div class="carousel-inner border">
                        <div class="carousel-item active">
                            <img class="w-100 h-100" src="/uploads/{{ $product->image }}" alt="image">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-7 pb-5">
                <h3 class="font-weight-semi-bold">{{ $product->product_name }}</h3>
                <br>
                <h4 class="font-weight-semi mb-4">{{ number_format($product->obtained)}} Points</h4>
                <p>Individual or Group (MAX 3 Person).</p>
                <div class="d-flex mb-3">
                    <p class="text-dark font-weight-medium mb-0 mr-3">Period:</p>
                    @php
                    $periods = explode(',',$product->period)
                    @endphp

                    @foreach ($periods as $period)
                    <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                        <input type="radio" class="period" id="{{ $period }}" name="period" value="{{ $period }}">
                        <label for="{{ $period }}">{{ $period }}</label>
                    </div>
                    @endforeach
                </div>
                <div class="d-flex align-items-center mb-4 pt-2">
                    <p class="text-dark font-weight-medium mb-0 mr-3">Quantity:</p>
                    <div class="input-group quantity mr-3" style="width: 130px;">
                        <input id="quantity" name="quantity" type="number" step="1" min="0" class="input quantity form-control bg-secondary text-center" value="1">
                    </div>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary px-3"><span>Add to Cart</span></a>
                </div>
                <div class="d-flex pt-2">
                    <p class="text-dark font-weight-medium mb-0 mr-2">Share on:</p>
                    <div class="d-inline-flex">
                        <a class="text-dark px-2" href="">
                            <i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i>
                        </a>
                        <a class="text-dark px-2" href="">
                            <i class="fab fa-twitter"></i>
                        </a>
                        <a class="text-dark px-2" href="">
                            <i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i>
                        </a>
                        <a class="text-dark px-2" href="">
                            <i class="fab fa-pinterest"></i>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row px-xl-5">
            <div class="col">
                <div class="nav nav-tabs justify-content-center border-secondary mb-4">
                    <a class="nav-item nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#tab-pane-1">Description</a>
                    <a class="nav-item nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#tab-pane-2">Information</a>
                    <a class="nav-item nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#tab-pane-3">Reviews (0)</a>
                </div>
                <div class="tab-content">
                    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="tab-pane-1">
                        <h4 class="mb-3">Activity Description</h4>
                        <p>{{ $product->description }}.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab-pane-2">
                        <h4 class="mb-3">Additional Information</h4>
                        <p>This activity has terms and conditions in order to request and complete it</p>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                                    <li class="list-group-item px-0">
                                        <h4 class="mb-3">Period</h4>
                                        <p>Students must complete the activity in between following dates : </p>
                                        <p>{{ $product->period }}</p>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="list-group-item px-0">
                                        <h4 class="mb-3">Location</h4>
                                        <p>The activity take a place in the following region :</p>
                                        <p>{{ $product->location }}</p>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="list-group-item px-0">
                                        <h4 class="mb-3">Requirements</h4>
                                        <p>Student must provide a few or specific data or document in order to able request it :</p>
                                        <p>{{ $product->requirements }}</p>
                                    </li>
                                  </ul> 
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab-pane-3">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <h4 class="mb-4">1 review for "{{ $product->product_name }}"</h4>
                                <div class="media mb-4">
                                    <img src="/front/img/user.jpg" png="Image" class="img-fluid mr-3 mt-1" style="width: 45px;">
                                    <div class="media-body">
                                        <h6>John Doe<small> - <i>01 Jan 2045</i></small></h6>
                                        <div class="text-primary mb-2">
                                            <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                                            <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                                            <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                                            <i class="fas fa-star-half-alt"></i>
                                            <i class="far fa-star"></i>
                                        </div>
                                        <p>Diam amet duo labore stet elitr ea clita ipsum, tempor labore accusam ipsum et no at. Kasd diam tempor rebum magna dolores sed sed eirmod ipsum.</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <h4 class="mb-4">Leave a review</h4>
                                <small>Your email address will not be published. Required fields are marked *</small>
                                <div class="d-flex my-3">
                                    <p class="mb-0 mr-2">Your Rating * :</p>
                                    <div class="text-primary">
                                        <i class="far fa-star"></i>
                                        <i class="far fa-star"></i>
                                        <i class="far fa-star"></i>
                                        <i class="far fa-star"></i>
                                        <i class="far fa-star"></i>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <form>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="message">Your Review *</label>
                                        <textarea id="message" cols="30" rows="5" class="form-control"></textarea>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="name">Your Name *</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="email">Your Email *</label>
                                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group mb-0">
                                        <input type="submit" value="Leave Your Review" class="btn btn-primary px-3">
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Shop Detail End -->
@endsection

@push('js')
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $('.add-to-cart').click(function(e){
                member_id = {{ Auth::guard('webmember')->user()->id }}
                id_product = {{ $product->id }}
                quantity = $('.quantity').val()
                period = $('.period').val()
                total = {{ $product->obtained }}*quantity
                is_checkout = 0

                $.ajax({
                    url : '/add_to_cart',
                    method : 'POST',
                    headers : {
                        "X-CSRF-TOKEN" : "{{ csrf_token() }}",
                    },
                    data: {
                        member_id,
                        id_product,
                        quantity,
                        period,
                        total,
                        is_checkout,
                    },
                    success : function (data) {
                        window.location.href = '/cart'
                    }
                });
            })
        })
        
    </script>
@endpush
```

This the add_to_cart controller and the web route :

```
public function add_to_cart(Request $request){
        $input = $request->all();
        Cart::create($input);
    }

Route::post('/add_to_cart', [HomeController::class,'add_to_cart']);
```

the code working if it successfully post the data to server and redirect me to cart page.

when i check the page source, the code succesfully get the member id and product id. but when i click the add to cart button after i select the period and quantity, it scrolls/jump me back to the top of the page, maybe it fails to get the selected data which is period and quantity if that true how come and any suggestion to fix it? Thank you.

Comment: Your "Add to cart" link is an `<a href="#"...`, so jumping to the top of the page is expected.

Comment: `$('.add-to-cart').click(function(e){` There is no element with that class in the code you posted

Comment: The `data` you post to your `.php` script should use keys/names (like `data: {member:member_id, product: product_id ...`) so you can access them in PHP

Comment: i do the data like you suggest but still dont work

Comment: Did you also add the class to your link? Do you know how to do basic debugging in your browser? Use the DevConsole/Network tab to see any XHR requests/responses, are there any errors? Does the data getting sent/received look ok? Maybe post how you handle incoming data in your PHP script, something might be wrong there

Comment: "_Did you also add the class to your link?_" remains unanswered. Take better care of the variables you send, `quantity = $('.quantity').val()` f.e.: you have a `<div>` with that same class. Use `console.log` to print out the values you want to send. Use `dd($request)` in your controller to debug. Good luck

Comment: alright thanks for the suggest, i'll try the suggestion for the moment